# POST request fails with error "object required"

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to send a POST request with VBScript.

```
Dim mydata
mydata=44

Set MyHttp=CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
MyHttp.open "POST", "http://www.example.com", False
MyHttp.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "MyCustomUser"
MyHttp.send mydata.XMLDocument
Document.Write MyHttp.responseText
```

Although I added the `mydata` value, it still gives "object required" error.

Answer (score 3):

You defined `mydata` as an integer value. Integer values don't have a property `XMLDocument`.

Change this:

```
MyHttp.send mydata.XMLDocument
```

into this:

```
MyHttp.send mydata
```

or create `mydata` as a proper object.